# How to locate the malicious code in my Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

Only today that it came to my attention that there is a malicious link that was injected in my wordpress site.

The link is only on the homepage of orphicpixel.com and here is the full code in html

```
<div class="toggle-search"><div id="5221f63">Learn how to extend your penis size using <a href="http://vigrx-plus-buy.com" title="vigrx reviews">vigrx reviews</a>.</div><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("36f1225".split("").reverse().join("")).style.display
= "none"</script><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
```

This are the fix that I tried.

1. Change the theme to default - the code is still there.
2. Turn off all the plugins - the code is gone.
3. I have identified 5 plugins that when turned on, the code appears. But the plugins are the official plugins like Jetpack, WP-pagination etc.
4. I search already my database but I got nothing.
5. I downloaded the theme files and search the codes, nothing
6. I downloaded all the plugins file and search the codes, nothing

So my last resort is to post this question here.

Comment: I don't see the link anywhere on orphicpixel.com, so it might be getting injected by some malware on your pc. Install adblock plus on your browser.

Comment: You can see when you view the source code or using Inspect element function of the browser. I tried in 3 pc and 1 mac already and as of the moment I am working on a Mac

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is likely hidden in something like an eval statement, which can be hidden in hex. Wordpress can be useful but the plugins are what make a security nightmare. It is likely that some plugin has allowed some kind of upload access to your site and they can run their own PHP script or anything really.

Look through your files using

```
find . -type f -mtime -1
```

The -1 is days back, you can try -2, -3 etc. If this is a recent problem hopefully this will show a recently modified file. It will look a lot like gibberish when you open a file that is bad.

Again unfortunately, if they are smart they will adjust the time on the file to be something a few weeks back or what ever, thus making the file much harder to find.

Answer (score -1):

Did you purchase your WordPress theme yourself and from the original provider? I would download **Theme Authenticity Checker** and run the plugin -- it finds malicious code within the theme. I know you checked the theme files, but better be safe than sorry. Usually, purchased themes have no problem but downloaded ones often have malicious code such as this.

Comment: What makes you say purchased themes have no problem but downloaded ones have? you might refer to premium hacked themes that you download for free from the internet maybe but themes hosted on wordpress.org that you can download and are free don't have this issue more then premium ones. Better refraze this answer..

Comment: Its a free theme that was downloaded from the developer's website. I am using TAC and no malicious code was detected and to make sure its not from the theme, as I mentioned in my initial post that I change the theme to the default but the problem still exist. I even downloaded a new version of the theme, delete the old on and activated the new one, but still, problem exist